# how to set width and height for data-src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I tried to set lazy loading of images in shopping website. Everything worked fine but when it comes for loading image that in "data-src" I find it difficult to set width and height for image inside data-src. Kindly help me with how to set height and width.

```
<img data-src="image/apple_600x450.jpg" src="img/loader.gif" style="width:100px; height:100px;" >
```

the above style works only for image inside src but it has no effect of data-src. Kindly help me to set

```
max-width
max-height
width
height
```

for image inside data-src.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well data-src is not an HTML feature but is being provided by a plugin. Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes sir, I am using bootstrap..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses `data-src` instead of `src`, it's because of the plugin `holder.js`. `data-src` is only used for the javascript library that generates the example images of a certain size, and `src` is the normal attribute for specifying the location of an image. See the [holder.js documentation here](https://github.com/imsky/holder).